# Postgresql: Update multiple rows using JSON input

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I am trying to update multiple rows if present in the table

**Sample input JSON: i_data**

```
i_data = {
"odId":"test",
"key":"dample",
"items":[{
   item_id: 1
   quantity : 10,
   statusId : 10
},
{
   item_id: 2
   quantity : 10,
   statusId : 10
}]
}
```

Update query - where needs some changes

```
UPDATE vw_item_status_detail vis 
SET
      quantity = (jst->>'quantity')::numeric,
      status_id = (jst->>'statusId')::numeric
FROM 
      jsonb_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') as jst
WHERE 
      jst->>'itemId' = vis.item_id;
```

Worked for updated!!! **solution is edited**

Insert  query where needs to be updated
getting error :more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
   INSERT INTO item (
      fulfiller_id,
      item_id,
      order_id,
      status_id,
      sku_code,
      decoration_technology,
      quantity,
      created_time)
   SELECT 
      i_data->>'fulfillerId' fulfillerId, 
      t->>'itemId' itemId, 
      i_data->>'orderId' orderId, 
      1000,
      t->>'skuCode' skuCode,
      t->>'decorationTechnology' decorationTechnology,
      (t->>'quantity')::numeric quantity ,
      NOW()
   FROM jsonb_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') t
WHERE
 NOT EXISTS (
        select vd.item_id FROM vw_item_status_detail vd WHERE vd.item_id = t->>'itemId'
    );;
```

Working for Insert query!!! **solution is edited**

Comment: Are you getting an error? Perhaps `ERROR:  column "item_id" does not exist`? JSON keys need to be quoted: `jst->>'item_id'`.

Comment: What's with that `v1` table and the `select distinct`? Shouldn't it be just `WHERE jst->>'item_id' = vis.item_id`? (possibly with an `::int` cast)

Comment: @Schwern I'd assume that (part of) the problem is that `item_id` actually does exist, as a column of `vis`.

Comment: @Bergi your solution helped. I also want to know how can i use where with insert 
```
 where t ->> 'itemId' !=  (select distinct v.item_id from vw_item_status_detail v);
```
this giving error saying- "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: @AagamDoshi In that case, you'll want `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE vw_item_status_detail vis 
SET
      quantity = (jst->>'quantity')::numeric,
      status_id = (jst->>'statusId')::numeric
FROM 
      jsonb_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') as jst
WHERE 
      jst->>'itemId' = vis.item_id;


   INSERT INTO item (
      fulfiller_id,
      item_id,
      order_id,
      status_id,
      sku_code,
      decoration_technology,
      quantity,
      created_time)
   SELECT 
      i_data->>'fulfillerId' fulfillerId, 
      t->>'itemId' itemId, 
      i_data->>'orderId' orderId, 
      1000,
      t->>'skuCode' skuCode,
      t->>'decorationTechnology' decorationTechnology,
      (t->>'quantity')::numeric quantity ,
      NOW()
   FROM jsonb_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') t
WHERE
 NOT EXISTS (
        select vd.item_id FROM vw_item_status_detail vd WHERE vd.item_id = t->>'itemId'
    );;
```

Working solution for upsert on views in postgresql